# Tkinter - ask a widget for its callback

Tags: python, testing, callback, tkinter

I'm trying to unit-test some Tkinter code. I want my tests to assert that my widgets have their callbacks set correctly. Is it possible to get hold of the Python function to which a Tkinter widget is bound?

I'd like to be able to write something like this:

```
def f():
    pass
b = ttk.Button(command=f)

assert b.command is f
```

Answer (score -2):

It would be a much better idea to put a `print` command in the function and then press the button to see what happens. If you don't want the code to execute, you can just comment out all the other code.

```
def func1():
    doStuff()
    print ("Function 1 has been called")

def func2():
    #doStuff2()
    print ("Function 2 has been called")

def func3():
    print ("Function 3 has been called")

button = Button(root, text="Call funaction 2", command=func2) #Etc....
```

EDIT:
I'm not sure if this is a good idea, but you can try using the `_tclCommands` variable in the button which will return a list. What's in the list? I'll be honest, I'm not entirely sure, but check this out from me trying it out:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> def epic():
...     print ("EPIC")
...
>>> b = Button(root, command=epic)
>>> b.grid()
>>> b._tclCommands
['28020208epic']
>>> epic
<function epic at 0x013D1468>
>>>
```

Comment: You haven't answered my question at all. I want [automated tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) which will run without intervention from me. I don't want to click buttons or look for print statements, and I certainly don't want to comment out code.

Comment: By clicking each button and seeing what has been printed, you can find out which function is tied to which button. Commenting out the code is just temporary for black-box testing.

Comment: A solution that involves manually clicking on buttons is not a solution. And yes, I know that `b['command']` will give you a string containing the function's `__name__`. (Presumably it's Tk's internal ID for the callback.) That doesn't really do the job though: I want to assert that the callback function _is_ a certain function, not that it happens to have the same name.

Comment: I think the short answer is !`b["command"] == f.__name__` is the best you are likely to get.